# Why did Mark Hamill want everyone to “flip the bird” in tribute to Carrie Fisher?

Tags: star-wars

According to a [*USA Today* article](https://www.usatoday.com/story/life/movies/2017/10/08/mark-hamill-carrie-fisher-meant-more-prominent-star-wars-episode-ix/743788001/), Mark Hamill told the crowd at a fan event on 10/7/17 to give Carrie the “one-finger salute” as some kind of sign of respect.

> "Worldwide, everyone feels that gap she left," Hamill continued. "But we all have to hang in there. And if she’s out there somewhere, we have to give her the one-finger salute. Come on everybody, for Carrie," he said, imploring the crowd to all raise their middle fingers in the air as a tribute to Fisher, 60.

What the heck is that all about? In the USA, raising your middle finger is considered vulgar and offensive, akin to saying “f*** you”.

Comment: http://mashable.com/2016/12/27/carrie-fisher-middle-finger/#FZeFS.bfssqs

Comment: I'm wondering why this belongs in SciFi&Fantasy, rather than, say, entertainment trivia. I understand the actors in question are involved in *Star Wars*, a decidedly fantasy movie, so is it the case that we may indulge in asking questions that surround sci-fi & fantasy properties, even if they are in themselves definitely not sci-fi & fantasy topics (like this question)?

Comment: @GhotiandChips It would seem to me to be clearly a science fiction & fantasy topic as Mark Hamill was speaking to science fiction & fantasy fans at a "fan event at New York Comic Con". Hamill wasn't hosting the event because of his role in Corvette Summer and wasn't talking about Carrie Fisher because of her role in The Blues Brothers. Specifically he was talking about Fisher in the context of what was to be her role in Star Wars Episode 9, her absence from that film being part of "that gap she left".

Comment: Also Mark Hamil's supply of "give-a-damn" is very, very low.

Comment: @RossRidge Well, actually, it wasn't that clear to me, no. I didn't know that criteria like that made for strong enough basis to warrant relevance in the context of a site like this, especially where "On-topic" is a quality that seems key to the ethos. Whether I disagree personally or not was actually irrelevant, I was merely looking for a semi-decent explanation, which you seem to have provided. Thank you.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Carrie Fisher famously gave George Lucas "the finger" at his AFI Lifetime Achievement Award ceremony (pictured bottom centre) when he made a joke about Carrie and her slave bikini. It kinda stuck and she would [often](https://www.indy100.com/article/carrie-fisher-death-christmas-day-2016-giving-people-the-finger-7498396) give the 'salute' at fan events.

[image]

Hamill described it as one of her favourite ways of ribbing people.

> “Well, I wish Carrie were here,” he said. “She would be making me
> laugh and be off camera extending her middle finger – one of her
> favorite gestures.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Mark Hamill: Carrie would be giving me the finger right now](https://www.binkily.com/mark-hamill-carrie-would-be-giving-me-the-finger-right-now/)</sup></sub>

Comment: Wow. Never knew that was her shtick.

Comment: @iMerchant: see further [her roasting George Lucas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZ97s396kb0), and [this lovely remembrance](https://www.theguardian.com/culture/2017/jan/03/carrie-fisher-sharon-horgan-so-real-it-was-dangerous) from another colleague and friend.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Her roast of Lucas was absolute gold and stole the show. “George, I hope it was you I slept with to get the job. If not, who the hell was it?”  Lolololol. Thanks for sharing

Comment: I hope that at least once when she did that, she also added "Live long and prosper".

Comment: @Simba - if only using one finger, wouldn't "Live long ***or*** prosper" be more appropriate?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet When you're king of the pride, you can still get both

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Take it easy...

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - If someone's using one finger, I suspect the implication is "*live long **and suffer"***

Comment: @Valorum - Or for others “*Yes, please!*”